# net use command asking for a username and password

Tags: authentication, azure-file-share

Azure Files SMB Access On-premises with private endpoints, But when I used the net use command to mount the drive.

c:>net use Z: \myshare.file.core.windows.net\testshare
its keep asking username passowrd
Enter the user name for myacc.file.core.windows.net':

Thanks
Shanuka M

Azure file share with On-prem AD Authentication

Answer (score 0):

Net use command fails if the storage account contains a forward slash

```html
Try the below mentioned cmdlet

New-SmbMapping -LocalPath z: -RemotePath \\StorageAccountName.file.core.windows.net\sharename -UserName StorageAccountName -Password "AccountPassword"
```

This article will help in [Mapping a Network Drive to an Azure File Share Using Domain Credentials](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/fasttrack-for-azure/mapping-a-network-drive-to-an-azure-file-share-using-domain/ba-p/2220773)

I would recommended to please refer the Prerequisites : [on-premises Active Directory Domain Services authentication over SMB for Azure file shares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-identity-auth-active-directory-enable)